# Does the camera automatic settings use CPU or GPU

Tags: raspicam, picamera

I have  simple questions:

I am using a program (pikrellcam) that has a number of automatic cameras settings, e.g. white balance, exposure, etc; and I am wondering if this puts a strain on the CPU or the GPU? And how much this may affect available RAM.

I am experiencing a lot of system freezes and one way to provoke them seems to be to have very changing light conditions, in addition to having the pi convert large video files. As I understand it the motion detection is the GPU but conversion from mp4 to H264 uses CPU.

Comment: "*Does the camera automatic settings use CPU or GPU?*" -- Short answer, GPU. -- [Encode to H264? That's all done on the GPU.](https://lb.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=168074#p1080622)